# How to use existing SignalR hubconnection in different pages in blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, signalr

I have Blazor application (client and Server).
In client application hub connection initialized in mainLayout with this code:

```
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/hub"), options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                {
                    var accessTokenResult = await AccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                    accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
                    return accessToken.Value;
                };
            }).Build();
```

This connection working fine in layout, but I don't understand how I get this connection to use on specific pages. I know how to get and use hubConnection in js, but not in blazor pages.

What I tried to do is to add a singleton to Main in program.css with this code :

```
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            var navMan = sp.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
            var accessTokenProvider = sp.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>();
            return new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(navMan.ToAbsoluteUri("/hub"), options =>
                {
                    options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                    {
                        var accessTokenResult = await accessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                        accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
                        return accessToken.Value;
                    };
                })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();
        });
```

But it didn't work because I don't have access to IAccessTokenProvider, it seems reasonably but without it connection useless because any request will be failed due to lack of permission.

Establishing connection each time when I change page not seem to right from me.

Also, it not seems right to have multiple connection to one or couple hub, its seem to me like overkill and resource demanding.

Comment: Blazor-server or WASM?

Comment: I use WASM + hub in blazor-server

Comment: Try adding as transient. By memory it is a lifetime issue. You can't inject the IAccessTokenProvider into the singleton.  Transient in WASM will give you the required lifetime.

Comment: @BrianParker you are right, now I don't have exception in program.cs, and now I have one builder but… Unfortunately It's not fully solves my problem, I still need to start a new connection on every page, and still get multiple connections.

Comment: You gave me idea, and now it's working right, I tried to use scoped service and now after starting connection ones in mainLayout I have the same connection from DI In all another pages. Now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a mistake to use Singleton.
Instead of singleton I added hubConnection as scoped like this :

```
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
        {
            var navMan = sp.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
            var accessTokenProvider = sp.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>();
            return new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(navMan.ToAbsoluteUri("/hub"), options =>
                {
                    options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                    {
                        var accessTokenResult = await accessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                        accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
                        return accessToken.Value;
                    };
                })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();
        });
```

and now I starting connection ones in mainLayout like this :

```
    [Inject] HubConnection _hubConnection { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => await StartupTask();

    async Task StartupTask()
    {
        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

after that all injection on another pages get same connection.